# add row note to a particular cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to add a comment to a particular cell of datagridview as the image below. Can it be done?
 [image]

Comment: Anything is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: :) yes. My approach is a new row that is added just below the row for which I need to add remarks. But that is not what I should look for because that seems to be a work around but not a good solution. Other approaches I thought was to append the remarks text to the cell. But here the problem is either the column width or row hight(word wrap) will will increase. That is also undesirable. I want exactly as in the picture.

Comment: But this comment will apprar only on a mouse hover, or it will be there written? One more thing, the "comment" should be over multiple cells in a row, as on the pucture?

Comment: This comment will be shown without mouse hover and should over multiple cells exactly as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some time I discovered the exact solution to prove that Matt is right.
Following is a beautiful link to do the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85kxk29c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **RowDetailsTemplate** with a *TextBlock* in it and databind its *Text* property.

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
  <!-- Put your columns here -->
  <sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Note}" />
     </DataTemplate>
  </sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I think your suggestion is for DataGrid not for DataGridView. Am I right? Also I am using windows forms and the above code is quite unfamiliar to me. Is it for WPF?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using WPF. I'll delete.

Answer (score 0):

I dount that is possible to add text over multiple cells in a row (in dgv control). Especilly if you want to keep the current text in cells, and add an extra text over these cells (like this comment).
So my answer s no, its not possible. But on the other hand, everything is possisble. You could create a new Label control, and position it on the right place, and add text into it. This means that the label would be actualy placed over the dgv control. This is one of thr idea.

I think if you wanna do something like you want to, you would have to do something extra (something unusual).

Comment: Ok...thnx..I will try ur suggested method.

Comment: can you please give some reference which guides to proceed in your suggested way. I could not find any material.